# How to import data from HDFS (Hadoop) into ElasticSearch?

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hive, hdfs

We have a big Hadoop cluster and recently installed Elastic Search for evaluation.

Now we want to bring data from HDFS to ElasticSearch.

ElasticSearch is installed in a different cluster and so far - we could run a Beeling or HDFS script to extract data from Hadoop into some file and then from a local file bulk load it to ElasticSearch.

Wondering if there is a direct connection from HDFS to ElasticSearch.
I start reading about it here: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/install.html

But since our team is not DevOps (does not configure nor manage Hadoop cluster) and can only access Hadoop via Kerberos/user/pass - wondering if this is possible to configure (and how) without involving whole DevOps team that manages Hadoop cluster to install/setup all these libraries before direct connect?

How to do it from a Client side?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to use Spark libraries to read from HDFS and load to Elasticsearch. The libraries would be embedded in the Spark code, not the Hadoop cluster... If you want to use Hive, you would upload the Elasticsearch jar to HDFS and use `ADD JAR` for elasticsearch driver before any query

Comment: Thanks. For HDFS - what jars would be needed for ElasticSearch before any query and would that needs to be set inside Hadoop cluster?

Comment: I believe that's mentioned here. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/hive.html